# collapse expandablelistview when press back button

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my app I need to collapse ExpandableListView  that already expanded when I press back button.
I can't find anything related online.
I have a large amount of data that should show in my expandable list view and I think it's so hard to collapse list by touching each Group manually.

```
Exp_List.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),Lessons_List.get(groupPosition)+ " is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside of `onBackPressed`, collapse all groups with a loop. If not groups collapsed, issue the default back press event:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ExpandableListView elv;
    boolean groupsCollapsed = false;
    for (int i=0; i<elv.getCount(); ++i) {
        if (elv.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
            elv.collapseGroup(i);
            groupsCollapsed = true;
        }
    }

    // If no groups collapsed, call the default back button
    if (!groupsCollapsed) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work, i have to change to  ExpandableListView elv=null; and after that when i pressed back button, error appears.